# Run Flask from run.sh

Tags: python, shell, flask

i have a problem, if you have any idea how it may be fixed, please help)

I have a project, which run by the .sh file, and this .sh refers to a python file.py which uses the Flask for html-reports.

When i run the file.py (for simplify with 'hello world'), but when i run the .sh file, it writes the error "ImportError: No module named 'flask'".

I installed the virtualenv for file.py's folder and .sh folder.

Please, give an advice for fix it. Thank's.

Comment: There a code      <pre>  <code>      #!/bin/sh
       export PROJ_DATA_FOR=../build/bin/data_for 
       export PROJ_OBJ=../build/bin/obj
    export PROJ_MEASURE=../build/bin/measure
   source env/bin/activate
   python3 scripts/file.py $1 <code>

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
pip install flask
```

or

```
pip3 install flask
```

the *flask* is the required module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the `virtualenv` first. In Linux you can do the following:

```
. env/bin/activate
```

Or:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Where `env` is where you initialized your virtualenv.

Then you can run you shell script.

As it has already been mentioned - if you haven't installed Flask install it after you have activated the virtualenv:

```
pip install flask
```

Comment: Not works.. i tried to activate virtualenv for folder with .py and for .sh. Flask had been installed, and .py work from command line, but when .sh requires, it doesn't see flask

Comment: You should add `source venv/bin/acitvate` before `python app.py` in your `run.sh`. For example [link](https://github.com/stamaimer/ZhiFang/blob/master/start.sh)

Comment: @E.Trofimov Could you paste your shell script in the question, otherwise we will not be able to help you.

Comment: @E.Trofimov What doesn't help?

Comment: Doesn't helps adding source venv/bin/acitvate before python app.py

Comment: @E.Trofimov Show your shell script and read the comments more attentively, please.

Comment: <pre><code>#!/bin/sh
export PROJ_DATA_FOR=../build/bin/data_for
export PROJ_OBJ=../build/bin/obj
export PROJ_MEASURE=../build/bin/measure
source env/bin/activate
python3 scripts/file.py $1 </code></pre>

Comment: @E.Trofimov What is $1? Do you pass any parameter to your python app?

Comment: @ Nurzhan  Doesn't(

Comment: @E.Trofimov Instead of `source` try to use `. env/bin/activate` or change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @E.Trofimov What OS are you using?

Comment: @ Nurzhan Linux Mint

Comment: @E.Trofimov Then I don't know what your problem is. It runs fine on my Ubuntu. Are you sure you did exactly as I told you?

Comment: will be trying to fix it.. but, more one question, for what folder is it correct to make virtualenv env ? I tried for both, but don't understand this moment

Comment: @E.Trofimov Usually, you initialize virtualenv in the same folder as your project. Also note that if you're using python3 then you need to initialize your virtualenv as `virtualenv -p python3 env' and then install using `pip` and run everything using `python` - no need to append `3`.

Comment: hmm..and is that normal that i havn't deactivate file in /env

Comment: @E.Trofimov I think it's better to deactivate it if you're not gonna use it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing wheel using:

`pip install wheel`

works, not sure what influenced it.